# How can I push operating system updates to remotely managed linux nodes?

Tags: remote, disk-image

I want to install a number of Raspberry Pi's in remote locations and push updates over the air to the operating system as necessary, in a way similar to mobile phones. There needs to be a partition for storing local data (such as wifi codes), so when it reboots it 'works'.

Is there a standard way of doing this in linux?

Comment: How is this related to professional IT?  Or is it?

Comment: It's similar to how you would remotely manage machines on a corporate Windows network; including re-imaging broken machines remotely.

Comment: You might wanna put that into your question, before it attracts anymore close votes. There's kind f a knee-jerk VTC reaction to things that aren't traditionally enterprise-grade, on account of the quantity of crap questions we get on a regular basis.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [create an local repository](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/ol_create_repo.html), attach the Raspberry settings to it and then you can reboot them with cronjobs with GIT or Puppet.